# OpenGL - Lights don't affect (only) glutSolidCone

Tags: opengl, rendering

As seen in the following image, I have a nice rendering with OpenGL using a mesh and OpenGL lights.

[image]

However, when I try to depict just the underlying skeleton of the hand, the ball-joints are depicted in a nice way, but OpenGL lights seem not to have an impact on the cone-bones, something that ruins the 3d perception of them.

[image]

Both the sptheres and the cones are depicted at the same point of the code (no intermediate things that can cause harm), using glut.

```
glutSolidSphere
glutSolidCone
```

The exact call to glutSolidCone (please ingore variables the set lenght, etc) is:

```
glutSolidCone( 2.2,boneLength-2*_screenshotWidth_Points,4,100*boneLength );
```

This has been pending for quite some time now, whenever I have some free time I look into this, but no luck up to now. Any hint?

Comment: Can you add the exact call to glutSolidCone?

Comment: done, as requested :)

Comment: Ok, so the cones are more like stretched pyramids, with a square bottom. Did you try to use > 4 slices?

Comment: Yep, but the result is the same..

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is, that in fixed function OpenGL (which is used by glutSolidCone) illumination calculations are done only at the vertices and then the resulting colors interpolated across the face. This of course looks bad if there are not enough vertices to sample the light falloff or specular highlights.

The most straightforward solution would be to drop in a per-fragment illumination shader program in compatibility profile mode, that uses the built-in variables instead of user supplied uniforms.

Comment: hm, sounds logical. I thought that more stacks introduce more vertices, but probable this doen't have any effect in the current problem. Due to time constraints, instead of the proposed solution, could one replace the glutSolidCones with something else in GLUT or similar?